# Delete service from the phone

Tags: android

How could you delete a service permanently, I couldn't remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Settings > Applications > Manage Applications will let you uninstall anything you installed yourself.

If for some reason that does not uninstall, I think a hard reset may be your only alternative, though I have not run into this problem yet myself.